# Why doesn't Sequence show up in list.__mro__ or list.__bases__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Consider this piece of code:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

print(issubclass(list, Sequence))  # Output: True
print(list.__mro__)   # Output: (<class 'list'>, <class 'object'>) 
print(list.__bases__)  # Output: (<class 'object'>,)
```

As you can see, the first print statement establishes that list is indeed a subclass of Sequence, but when I try to enumerate its superclasses using __mro__ or __bases__, I only get object as the superclass which means there are no more superclasses higher up.
Why don't __bases__ and __mro__ list Sequence as a parent class when it actually is?

Comment: It's a _virtual_ subclass - it implements then interface but doesn't inherit the ABC - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html.